# Cannot ping clients on WLAN from RasPi

Tags: networking, wifi, access-point, ping

Installed fresh 2020-02-13-raspbian-buster-full
Did apt-get updates.
I have a Pi connected to my Ethernet network behind a router connected to the Internet.
I am running apps on the Pi that I can access from the local network.
The Pi is a WiFi AP for clients.
The WiFi clients can all access the internet and apps on the Pi.
I cannot ping or access the WiFi clients from the Pi.
Setup the following:

- hostapd
- dnsmasq
- net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

Create `/etc/sysctl.d/routed-ap.conf`

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

Created `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`

```
interface=wlan1
dhcp-range=192.168.16.2,192.168.16.254,255.255.255.0,24h
domain=wlan
address=/gw.wlan/192.168.16.1
```

Create `/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf`

```
interface=wlan1
driver=nl80211
ssid=NodeRed
hw_mode=g
channel=11
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=MySuperSecretPasscode
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
#wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

Edit the file `/etc/default/hostapd`

```
DAEMON_CONF="/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf"
```

Some debug output:

```
rpi ~$ ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
      inet 192.168.15.100  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.15.255

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)

wlan1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.16.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.16.255

rpi ~$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:4d:26:a6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.15.100/24 brd 192.168.15.255 scope global noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2605:e000:1703:826e:88e3:ac4d:9766:aed7/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute
       valid_lft 405885sec preferred_lft 405885sec
    inet6 fe80::3572:c6ea:28ed:5eb7/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:18:73:f3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: wlan1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 9c:ef:d5:fe:80:c1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.16.1/24 brd 192.168.16.255 scope global noprefixroute wlan1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::9f82:f9d8:d9c1:edd/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

rpi ~$ ip route
default via 192.168.15.1 dev eth0 src 192.168.15.100 metric 202
192.168.15.0/24 dev eth0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.15.100 metric 202
192.168.16.0/24 dev wlan1 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.16.1 metric 304

rpi ~$ iptables --nat --list --verbose
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 3149 packets, 512K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 1938 packets, 171K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 9 packets, 1543 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 1589  371K MASQUERADE  all  --  any    eth0    anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 718 packets, 48585 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Oops:
Leaving post as it is (I think) the right way to setup an AP.
Found out today that the Client was actually connecting to a different AP.
It is an appliance so it was not obvious at the time.
The clients were showing up in the leases file, because they had connected but just not currently connected.

Comment: Please [edit]( https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/112754/edit) your question and add the output of these commands to it: `ip addr`, `ip route` and `sudo iptables --table nat --list --verbose`.

Comment: What the *Oops* sentence mean? Problem solved if connecting to the right access point? What Raspberry Pi do you use?  Why do you use an additional WiFi adapter?

Comment: Yes, when testing initially I had connected the appliance to the main WiFi. After setting up the Pi I then connected to the Pi WiFi. During testing and rebooting the Pi, the appliance connected to the other WiFi.
I have deleted the other WiFi network from the appliance to prevent further issues.
Pi 3. WiFi is not that good from my experience. I use a USB one with a real antenna. And that had nothing to with the issue.

Comment: Please write an answer with the solution and accept it after two days. Only accepting an answer will finish the question and it will not pop up again and again for years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, when testing initially I had connected the appliance to the main WiFi. After setting up the Pi I then connected to the Pi WiFi. During testing and rebooting the Pi, the appliance connected to the other WiFi.

Pi 3. WiFi is not that good from my experience. I use one with a real antenna. And that had nothing to with the issue.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.